# How to convert <img> to AMP in PHP

Tags: php, html, amp-html

I have problem when covert old html code to AMP version:

My document with many image, but only have width value in source code.

```
<img src="/url-img1.jpg" with="728"></img>
<img src="/url-img2.jpg" with="640"></img>
```

In AMP version i need add height value as below:

```
<amp-img src="/url-img1.jpg" width="{widht-of-image}" height="{height-of-image}" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
<amp-img src="/url-img2.jpg" width="{widht-of-image}" height="{height-of-image}" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
```

Can anyone pls tell me how to do it?

Comment: This source perhaps can be useful and I found it work successfully: https://gist.github.com/elalemanyo/034490164beb7b935559585ff1cc7d9f

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize('path_to_the_image/url-img1.jpg');
echo '<amp-img src="/url-img1.jpg" width="'. $width .'" height="'. $height . '" layout="responsive"></amp-img>';
```

However, this defeats a bit the purpose of AMP which is that the resources are loaded at the end. Caching on their side should solve these issues, but still my advise is that you are hardcoding the width, you also hardcode the height. You could automate this once and then replace them for all.